# Azure Blob Storage only shows one file at a time

Tags: visual-studio, azure, visual-studio-2015, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I have this following method which uploads file to blob storage:

```
public static string UploadToBlob(string filePath, string container)
{
  if (!File.Exists(filePath))
    return string.Empty;

  var fileContent = File.ReadAllBytes(filePath);

  var fileName = Path.GetFileName(filePath);
  var blobPath = $"/{Guid.NewGuid()}/{fileName}";
  var azStorage = new AzureBlobStorage(ConfigurationHelper.GetConnectionAsString("StorageConnectionString"));

  return azStorage.Upload(container, blobPath, fileContent, fileName);
}
```

which then I execute inside a foreach loop as so:

```
FileProcessor.UploadToBlob(filePathLocal, StorageBlobContainers.ArcoExtractionPdfs);
```

When I navigate insider server explorer, I can see the blob:

[image]

but when I enter it, there's only one file showing:

[image]

However, if I delete this file and hit refresh, another one shows up, and by repeating this I can see all of them, one by one..

[image]

How can I see all the files in my blob at once?

Comment: I've had good luck with the new Microsoft Azure Storage Explorer app: http://storageexplorer.com/

Comment: Alright, I've downloaded it. App seems pretty cool, but it behaves the exact same way. :/

Comment: Where are you getting the AzureBlobStorage class? I usually us CloudStorageAccount and CloudBlobClient. Is there a  Nuget package or some other library you are using?

Comment: @iuliu.net It seems that your code wrapped Azure Storage SDK APIs, is it? And the code `var blobPath = $"/{Guid.NewGuid()}/{fileName}";` seems that you want to create a directory named `Guid.NewGuid()` to upload a file on the container `arcoextractionpdfs`. It's not correct for using Azure Storage, please see the section [`Blob service concepts`](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-dotnet-how-to-use-blobs/#blob-service-concepts).